# Rails - best way to get checkbox value and set checked status based on parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a form in Rails that when submitted, reloads the same page with the parameters and displays some data.

I have a checkbox on the form that I want to have checked or unchecked based on what was just submitted.

Here's what I have in my controller-

```
@show_values = false

  if params[:check_value] == "1"
    @show_values = true
  end
```

Then in my view, I have the following-

```
   <% if @show_breakfast%>
      <div class="row"><%= check_box_tag 'check_value', 1,  {:checked => "checked"}%> Show X</div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="row"><%= check_box_tag 'check_value', 1%> Show X</div>
    <% end %>
```

This is working the way I want, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do this.

Comment: Use a model to represent the form elements, then you can use a form builder to create your form. It takes values from the model, so you only need one instance variable for all form values. I would post code, but you can just use the scaffold generator to see an example...

Comment: This form is for a search form, not a form to create an object which is why I didn't use the form builder. Could a search form be easily done with the same form builder syntax?

Comment: Sounds like you need a form object, I'll add an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'form object' when you want a complex form - or one that isn't attached to a model. Make a new folder under 'app' called forms or something. Then create your form's shell:

In Rails 3:

```
class SearchForm
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

In Rails 4:

```
class SearchForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Add in some attr_accessors for your fields:

```
class SearchForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :check_value, :title, :another_field
  ...
```

Add validators if you like, you get this behaviour from including and extending ActiveModel:

```
  ...
  validates :title, presence: true
```

Then a process method:

```
  ...
  def process(params)
    params = params[:search_form]
    self.check_value = params[:check_value]
    self.title = params[:title]
    self.another_field = params[:another_field]

    if valid?
      #Do any processing you may need to do, including stuff like sanitising inputs.
      return true
    end
    false
  end
```

Now you can use it just like a model in your controller.

```
def search
  @form = SearchForm.new
  @form.process[params]
  flash.now[:error] = "Invalid search input" unless @form.valid? # or whatever.
end
```

And it behaves like a model so you can use your favourite form builder.

Comment: Added advantages: No need for annoying attr_accessible or strong params; you're specifying parameters explicitly by form. Also, you can eliminate the need for nested forms/attributes - just have the form object update multiple models. The level of abstraction means that you can change a model's interface without having to update both the controller and the views - just adapt the form object. And you can put form logic in an appropriate object rather than polluting the controller or a model...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but if you want to keep the same approach, I would only have this in the view:

```
<div class="row"><%= check_box_tag 'check_value', 1,  @show_breakfast %> Show X</div>
```