# Nested Form in Rails 4 not being rendered in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Apologies if this has already been answered but I can't find anything that can help me. I am a newbie with Rails so please be gentle :D

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get nested forms working, I am sure I got nested forms working using Rails 3 and the railscasts demo last year, but Rails 4 is beating me.

Looking at the log, the query is being run to pull the data for the associated table, but nothing is rendered in the form.

I have read many web sites, but none have helped so far and I don't know where to start. The latest article I have followed is this http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/

Still nothing being rendered in the view.

Where do I start debugging this, maybe my Rails install is broken?? But I am probably missing something crucial.

Thanks,
Royce

Edit - I have added some of the controllers and the view in question

surveys_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :answers]

  # GET /surveys
  # GET /surveys.json
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  # GET /surveys/1
  # GET /surveys/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  # GET /surveys/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /surveys
  # POST /surveys.json
  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /surveys/1
  # PATCH/PUT /surveys/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.update(survey_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /surveys/1
  # DELETE /surveys/1.json
  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to surveys_url, notice: 'Survey was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def answers
    @participants = Participant.all
    @questions = @survey.questions
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:name,
      :questions_attributes => [:id, :content,
        :answers_attributes => [:id, :content, :participant_id]
      ])
    end
end
```

participents_controller.rb

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_participant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /participants
  # GET /participants.json
  def index
    @participants = Participant.all
  end

  # GET /participants/1
  # GET /participants/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /participants/new
  def new
    @participant = Participant.new
  end

  # GET /participants/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /participants
  # POST /participants.json
  def create
    @participant = Participant.new(participant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Participant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @participant }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /participants/1
  # PATCH/PUT /participants/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.update(participant_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Participant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @participant }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /participants/1
  # DELETE /participants/1.json
  def destroy
    @participant.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to participants_url, notice: 'Participant was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_participant
      @participant = Participant.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def participant_params
      params.require(:participant).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

answers.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @survey.name %> Answers</h1>

<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% @participants.each do |participant| -%>
  <h3><%= participant.name %></h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Questions</td>
        <td>Answer</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @questions.each do |question| -%>
      <tr>
        <td><%= question.content %></td>
        <td>
        <%= f.fields_for :questions, question do |q| -%>
          <%= q.fields_for :answers, question.answers.find_or_initialize_by(participant: participant) do |a| -%>
            <%= a.text_area :content %>
            <%= a.hidden_field :participant_id, participant.id %>
          <% end -%>
        <% end -%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end -%>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% end -%>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Quick suggestion: post a little code here. Perhaps the controller method and the view itself.

Comment: Cheers Myles, hope that helps.

Comment: please post the content of survey model. You are probably missing `accept_nested_attributes_for  :questions`

Comment: Nested forms are ugly, confusing and brittle - and you need to remember to do lots of little things correctly throughout the stack. You can make things a lot simpler to understand and help to isolate changes by using form objects. Form objects pretend to be models, so they work in the same way as models when dealing with the controller or view. There's a pro Railscast about it, or see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296385/rails-best-way-to-get-checkbox-value-and-set-checked-status-based-on-parameter/25298020#25298020

Comment: That looks interesting, will have to read up on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're new with Rails, let me explain how nested forms work for you!

--

**Nested**

*Nested* forms are not actually nested at all - they are *associative* forms.

You must remember that Rails (by virtue of being built on Ruby) is an [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework. OOP (object orientated programming) is not just a buzzword - it's a fundamental core construction for your application & how it hands input / execution.

The problem many people have is they don't realize the true nature of Rails, and consequently become confused about how its many features work. If you appreciate that **everything you do in Rails should be constructed *around* objects**, life gets much simpler!

[image]

--

**Form**

With this in mind, you can begin to appreciate the role of `object`s throughout Rails, to the degree that you need to build / invoke objects for every element of your Rails application, including your form:

```
#app/models/survey.rb
Class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :questions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

#app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb
Class SurveysController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @survey = Survey.new
       @survey.questions.build #-> very important
   end
end

#app/views/surveys/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| %>
      <%= q.text_field :title %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should create a form which allows you to pass associative data through to your child model. There are several important elements to consider:

> 1. You need to include [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your "parent" model
> 2. You need to `build` your associative objects
> 3. You need to populate your form with the relative objects

By following this simple pattern, you'll be able to populate the nested form that you wish to show in the view

Comment: Thanks Rich, I missed @survey.questions.build Just need to work out why my main project doesn't work now! Same problem.

Comment: No problem - what's the issue with your main project? Maybe we could fix it?

Comment: Same issue Rich, form not rendering nested attributes. The code above was an attempt to find out why it wasn't working. Have done exactly the same in the main project but doesn't render.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got accepts_nested_attributes_for :question in your survey model? And the same for the answer model?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| -%>
      <%= q.fields_for :answers, q.object.answers.find_or_initialize_by(participant: f.object.participant) do |a| -%>
        <%= a.text_area :content %>
        <%= a.hidden_field :participant_id, participant.id %>
      <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
```

and make sure that you render to `answers.html.erb`, you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` in `survey.rb` file, and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers` in `question.rb` file