# Checking Checkbox in View based on Field Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

In my application I have splits and issues. I have the issue_id on my splits table and if the issue_id for a split contains 1 I want to show the checkbox for that split as checked.

I have the checkbox getting checked, but it's checking all of them regardless of what the content of issue_id is.

Here is my controller code:

```
@selected_split = false

if params[:issue_id] == "1"
  @selected_split = true
end
```

Here is an abbreviation of the code I have in my index view:

```
<% @splits.each do |split| %>
  <tr>
     <td><%= check_box_tag 'issue_id', 1,  {:checked => "checked"}%></td> 
     <td><%= link_to split.name, split_path(split) %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I've looked at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296385/rails-best-way-to-get-checkbox-value-and-set-checked-status-based-on-parameter) as an example, but like I said it's checking all of the checkboxes.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `true` to 3rd parameter in `check_box_tag` to make the checkbox checked, something like this:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'issue_id', 1, split.issue_id == 1 %></td>
```

Comment: Humm, now all of the checkboxes are unchecked. I checked my database and there are several items that have a value of 1 in issue_id

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does your `issue_id` belongs to `split` model?

Comment: That did it. The issue_id is the field that ties the split and the issue models together. Thanks!